# Alternate landscape triggered at unwanted view

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller that contains an image and a tableview. From this view controller I connected a segue to a landscape view that contains the image in full screen (same idea used when you turn sideways the Stocks app from Apple to see the graph in full screen).

This segue is called by the following method:

```
- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"toGraph" sender: self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Besides this, when the iphone is at portrait orientation, I can also drill-down the tableview a couple more levels. The problem is the following: at those consequent levels, the segue to the landscape view still gets triggered when I turn the orientation to landscape!... what can I do so that this does not happen? I am only interested in going to landscape mode from the first view which contains the image.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if I got your issue right.. but if you mean with "drill-down the table view" to go deeper in a navigation controller hierachy, you can try the following..

That's what I did in a (I think) similar situation:

AppDelegate:

in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutorotate;
```

in .m:

// in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.shouldAutorotate = NO;
```

// still in .m file

```
// Autorotation handling
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return self.shouldAutorotate ?
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown :
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Navigation Controller presenting Portrait Controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.selectedViewController)
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Portrait View Controller (here's also a very similar segue handling that you have):

in viewWillAppear:

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setShouldAutorotate:YES];
```

rotation handling:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Landscape View Controller (probably your full screen image):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Deeper in the navigation controller hierachy (where only portrait is wanted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Looks somehow complicated, but that was the only way, I managed to get those rotation things working properly in both iOS5 and 6.

Comment: I think you understood fine!... but I don't understand what does this line of code mean: [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setShouldAutorotate:YES];

Comment: This will set the "shouldAutorotate" property in the AppDelegate to "YES".. So this should activate autorotation for the one Portrait Controller where the Landscape Controller is segued from.

Comment: When I place that line of code in my project, it tells me "Use of undeclared identifier: AppDelegate", what am I missing? I'm sorry to keep bothering you but I'm still a rookie programming.

Comment: Did you put @property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutorotate; in the AppDelegate's Header file? And did you #import AppDelegate in your Portrait view Controller?

Comment: Ohh I had not imported the AppDelegate!!... Now I did but the landscape View keeps showing up at every level of the navigation hierarchy :( there must be some code conflicting with what you suggested (which looks pretty neat)... I'll dig some more into the code I had to see where the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer according to what I have in the navigation controller (presenting the portrait view controller) for the rotation stuff.. Maybe this will fix it for you.