# Details on rotation and custom view objects

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview, screen-rotation

I have setup a custom view with two subviews and a button. I am trying to understand CGRect better and work out what should be used for heights/widths and how to center items correctly. I imagine that using exact numbers like this:

```
UIButton *facebookLoginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300,75)];
```

... is not the correct way to complete this. When the device is rotated nothing fits to screen anymore.

I would also like to know how to not allow rotation on one view controller. For example a setting which I can stop rotate doing anything with the views, then later in the app rotation will be used again.

I have had a look through the design apple documentation but not sure exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for best practice for setting bounds/center items/sizes(width/heights)/working with multiple sub views and how they layout when programatically creating the views.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the device orientation and then adjust the sizes regarding to that.

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

If you're using iOS6 you can take a look at constraints. Or just use the interface builder, where it's pretty simple to manage that stuff (if you don't need to make it programmatically).

For portrait / landscape orientation, check this out:
[Alternate landscape triggered at unwanted view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650127/alternate-landscape-triggered-at-unwanted-view/14651219#14651219)

With that I managed to perform a landscape rotation only on one view controller while all the rest of the app stays in portrait (but you can adopt for your needs of course).

Comment: In this example, I want one screen to only show portrait, others will show as both. I prefer to programatically create rather than using interface builder so I am looking for information on how to handle widths/heights based on the screen size for the different phone screens (iphone5) too

Comment: Did you take a look at constraints (I think that's exactly what you're looking for)? Just to find out the screen size, you can use     [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height and then adopt stuff depending on the result.

Comment: I am using IOS5. Yes I am looking for more information that using the main screen size. For example, what happens when orientation changes? How can I use the height of the screen/width of the screen to help show a button equal distant from the edges when both portrait and landscape? This is the sort of information I am looking for, I am happy to go through the documentation but not sure what to look for and where to find this...

Comment: But then I think [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size is exactly what you're looking for. Left and top distances should be easy (as that's the coordinate systems origin), for right and bottom you have to do some calculations using the screen and button sizes and positions, but this should also be no big deal.